# How to make query paramerized using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with Nodejs and using expressjs,Right now i am using "insert query" but i want to make query more secure
means i want to use "connection.query" (paramerized query),How can i do this ? Also i want to know that how can we get "last inserted id" in express js ? Here is my current code

```
static async addServiceDetail(userId,serviceId,genderTypeId,price,serviceName)
    {
        const sql = `SELECT id from servicesdetail WHERE userId='${userId}' AND  serviceId='${serviceId}' AND genderTypeId='genderTypeId'`;
        const [rows, fields] = await pool.execute(sql);
        if(rows<1)
            {
                const sql2 = `INSERT INTO servicesdetail (userId, serviceId, genderTypeId,price,serviceName) VALUES ("${userId}", "${serviceId}", "${genderTypeId}", "${price}","${serviceName}")`;
                console.log('query is '+ sql);
               const datass = await pool.execute(sql2);
                console.log('last inserted id is ' +datass.insertId);
                
            }
        else
            {
                console.log('already exist');
            }   
    }
```

Comment: What node sql package are you using? mysql? mysql2?

Comment: @abney317 i think "mysql" , kindly give me answer so i can check

Comment: You might like my article that goes into this: https://evertpot.com/executing-a-mysql-query-in-nodejs/

Comment: @Evert can we change in current code ? if yes then how ? kindly post your answer so i can check

Comment: @Diana sorry I don't care about the points. Just wanted to give you a pointed to help you help yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) driver of the node, it is possible to pass parameters as follows:

Query would look like this:

```
const resultSelect = await pool.execute(`SELECT id from servicesdetail WHERE userId = ? AND  serviceId = ? AND genderTypeId='genderTypeId'`,[userId, serviceId])
```

Insert would look like this:

```
const resultInsert = await pool.execute(`INSERT INTO servicesdetail (userId, serviceId, genderTypeId,price,serviceName) VALUES (?, ?,  ?, ?, ?)`,[userId, serviceId, genderTypeId, price, serviceName]);
```

For the case of obtaining the last identifier, it is possible through the query:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(ID) From servicesdetail;
```

But it is necessary to read the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) calmly and see if the table structure has an ID with auto_increment, if the identifier does not have auto_increment it may not work, in addition to the observation note that the documentation itself informs "If you insert multiple rows using a single INSERT statement, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the value generated for the first inserted row only. The reason for this is to make it possible to reproduce easily the same INSERT statement against some other server.".

hope i helped ;D

Comment: Ravache can we get last inserted id without another query ?

Comment: If you have a table without auto_increment, you can search with Select max(userId) from servicesdetail , if you want to add it to the insert, it would look like this const resultInsert = await pool.execute(`INSERT INTO servicesdetail (userId, serviceId, genderTypeId,price,serviceName) VALUES ((select max(userId)+1 as userId from servicesdetail), ?,  ?, ?, ?)`,[userId, serviceId, genderTypeId, price, serviceName]) , in this case, it inserts the identifier according to the last identifier inserted + 1.